# Passing flags to make in bash script fails

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile

I have a build script in bash which does something like:

```
if [[ $DEBUG ]]; then
    MAKE_CMD="$MAKE_CMD $DEBUG_FLAGS"
fi
```

$DEBUG_FLAGS are initialized to:

```
DEBUG_FLAGS="GDB_FLAG='-g' OTHER_CFLAGS='-O0 -g'"
```

then I just use $MAKE_CMD to compile the code. The script works without adding DEBUG_FLAGS to the original make command but adding the flags causes issues. It also works if I type in the $MAKE_CMD by hand with the same debug flags. The only thing I can deduce is that my quotation is wrong which is causing issues. Do you see something wrong with my quotations?

Comment: A lot depends on exactly how you use `$MAKE_CMD`, which you did not show in your question.  Also, you only describe how it _does_ work, you never say exactly how it _doesn't_ work.  What error or incorrect behavior do you observe?

Comment: You have asked enough questions to know what a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org) is. What "issues"? How exactly do you refrain from adding `DEBUG_FLAGS`? What if you do without the conditional? What is the value of `MAKE_CMD`? What if you try that very command without the extra steps?

Comment: Embedded quotes are treated literally. When you run `MAKE_CMD`, `DEBUG_FLAGS` consists of 3 words: `GDB_FLAG='-g'`, `OTHER_CFLAGS='-O0`, and `-g'`. If you post some more details about what you are trying to do and the context in which you do it, someone may be able to suggest something that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**make.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

MAKE_CMD="make -f bash.mak"
DEBUG_FLAGS="GDB_FLAG='-g' OTHER_CFLAGS='-O0 -g'"

if [[ $DEBUG ]]; then
  MAKE_CMD="$MAKE_CMD $DEBUG_FLAGS"
fi

eval $MAKE_CMD
```

**bash.mak**: (mind the tabs vs spaces!)

```
all:
        echo $(GDB_FLAG)
        echo $(OTHER_CFLAGS)
```

Command line example:

```
$ DEBUG=true ./make.sh
echo -g
-g
echo -O0 -g
-O0 -g
```